# .net standard conform open source PDF library

Tags: open-source, library, c#, .net, api

I wanted to know if someone knows a good .NetStandard conform library to create PDFs.

### Task I want to perform

The goal is to extend a static site generator that transforms Markdown to HTML to also provide a book version for some parts of the site (transforming the Markdown to PDF using some templates to apply styles section wise).

The output PDF should have

- different background images

  - *for different chapters*
- multi column layout
- additional textboxes / images / tables

  - *that can be referenced from text*
- text references

The PDF will be used as full color rulebook for a game.

---

I do not search a library that does everything for me. But I wouldn't mind to use it, if it already exists.

A simple library that allows to print text, images, and other things on a page would be enough (as long as I can find out the size of the text before it is printed).

With this I could try to create a library that would be something like LaTeX (but most likely not as power full and performant ;)) that will be consumed by the static site generator.

### Aditional requirements

- Open Source (should be consumable by an MIT library)
- .NetStandard (with a maintained nuget package)

---

I looked already at PdfSharp, but unfortunately it does not work with .NetStandard, like all other libs I saw.